# Inject an html table into an image available as an ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, html, image, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Basically I want to go from here (available as an ArrayBuffer):

[image: ArrayBuffer]

to here: (also available as an ArrayBuffer)+
[image]

So it's

**ArrayBuffer -> Image -> Image with overlay -> ArrayBuffer**

in javascript only without showing anything to the user.

If possible, I want to generate that table using html (still without showing anything to the user).

I had that idea of displaying an invisible Chrome Appwindow to render the page with the image as its background just to export it using the html2canvas library.

However, there has to be a better approach to this ...
Does anyone have an idea of how to implement such a functionality?

Comment: You can use `<canvas>`

Comment: But is that invisible to the user? I really want to do all the processing in the background.js of a chrome application only without the need of opening a new window. How would I load an image into a canvas tag without displaying some sort of webpage?

Comment: `<canvas>` does not need to be displayed to call `.drawImage()`

Comment: Ok, so I create a dom object by using jQuery.parsehtml and then do all the modifications to the included canvas and then I store the thing as an ArrayBuffer let's see if that works :) thanks!